# After adding Prism.unity 6.2.0 to Windows 10 UWP, application throws exception

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

When creating a Universal Windows Application with Prism, I always receive an error upon running the application (or, sometimes, upon exiting the running application).  Here are the steps I take to reproduce the problem:

- Create a new UWP application Using Visual Studio 2015.
- Use NuGet to install Prism (Install-Package Prism.unity)
- Change the App class to inherit from PrismUnityApplication (code below)
- Create a folder called Views and add a new page called MainPage, making sure that it is in the correct namespace

Code:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Prism.Events;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Unity.Windows;
using Prism.Windows.AppModel;
using Prism.Windows.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace TestAppForPrism {
/// <summary>
/// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
/// </summary>
sealed partial class App : PrismUnityApplication {

    public App() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) {
        NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    protected override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args) {
        Container.RegisterInstance<INavigationService>(NavigationService);

        return base.OnInitializeAsync(args);
    }
}
}
```

When I run the application, an exception is thrown:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Am I setting things up incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default UWP template in Visual Studio 2015 still comes with `"Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.1.0"`, while this should be version 5.2.2.

So simply update that package to 5.2.2 and everything should work.

---

Small sidenote on your code:

- return Task.CompletedTask if you don't have to execute a task. This is added in .NET 4.6. It's a bit more performant.
- there's no need to register the INavigationService in your container, that's already done in the base class.

So your code can be trimmed down to

```
sealed partial class App : PrismUnityApplication
{

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around for a while, I think I found a solution:

In the NuGet console, I ran "update-package -reinstall", and then rebuilt the solution.  I still have a warning in the error window that says "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.", but I seem to be able to run the application without receiving that exception any more.